# SWF Actionscript encryption, ununderstandable code

Tags: encryption, actionscript, flash

I ran through an encrypted SWF yesterday, and I could note a part of actionscript as follows:

```
if(19228849284 == 192246636643) {
 ... //other statements continued
}
```

My question is, how could that code ever get executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the comparison of two timestamps. Perhaps for whatever reason these timestamps are hardcoded in the application and compared at this point. The code obviously won't be executed. Actually, it's strange that the Flash compiler didn't optimize it out.